# Pyspark Kafka Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to get a spark cluster to work properly. Please note it was setup by someone else. I'm trying to incorporate Kafka through Spark Streaming, but whenever I attempt to use PySpark I get the following error, even when not utilizing Spark Streaming.

From what I understand the Spark Master is sending the worker nodes the location of the kafka-streaming jar using the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` inside the `spark-defaults.conf` file and the jar is in the correct location on all the nodes, including the master.

One thing I'm finding odd is that the nodes appear to be looking for the jar in the `/jar` directory when the `spark-defaults.con` file indicates the jar is located in `/usr/local/src`.

I reset all the nodes after making changes, I even removed the jar's reference, but the nodes still look for it.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3d993e9922f2> in <module>()
----> 1 data = df.select('subject_id', 'date').where("stats is not null and date > '2009-10-31' and date < '2010-03-01'").first()

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in first(self)
    804         Row(age=2, name=u'Alice')
    805         """
--> 806         return self.head()
    807 
    808     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in head(self, n)
    792         """
    793         if n is None:
--> 794             rs = self.head(1)
    795             return rs[0] if rs else None
    796         return self.take(n)

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in head(self, n)
    794             rs = self.head(1)
    795             return rs[0] if rs else None
--> 796         return self.take(n)
    797 
    798     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in take(self, num)
    348         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
    349             port = self._sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(
--> 350                 self._jdf, num)
    351         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    352 

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    931         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    932         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 933             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    934 
    935         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/src/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    310                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    311                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 312                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    313             else:
    314                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.95.96.142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.1.jar' was not found.
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:223)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply$mcI$sp(EvaluatePython.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(EvaluatePython.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$$anonfun$takeAndServe$1.apply(EvaluatePython.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$.takeAndServe(EvaluatePython.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe(EvaluatePython.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.1.jar' was not found.
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:223)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue boiled down to finding where the configuration was actually being set. After I found the call to spark-submit I found that the jars added were being delimited with a `:` and not a `,`, so spark was considering the multiple jars as a single jar. Interesting thing is that the stacktrace considered the `:` delimiter and only gave spark-streaming-kafka as not being found.

Answer (score 1):

download this

> http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.0.2%22

and run as

```
spark-submit --jars /yourpath/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.2.jar test.py
```

Comment: for more info http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html